# Printing a circular buffer

Tags: c, arrays, printing, struct, circular-buffer

I'm wondering how do I print out this giant circular buffer. The first 3 blocks are structs and the while loop is in a main, this is only part of my code. I'm not focusing the format or the output right now. This is just an idea what I should be getting. This line is where i'm focusing at:

```
// copies from and to destination of the string of the timestamp and the value.
strcpy(chart.buffer[asci].reading[chart.buffer[asci].end].timestamp,
  current.field[1]);
```

My input is:

```
5, 08:00:00, 2, 60  
5, 08:00:01, 5, 15  
5, 08:00:10, 1, 986                     
5, 08:05:24, 2, 61  
5, 08:07:21, 2, 58  
5, 08:10:11, 6, 0
```

My output should be:

```
 
Readings for Patient ID = 5 are:  
Temperature:  
08:00:10: 98.6   
Heart Rate:  
08:00:00: 60  
08:05:24: 61  
08:07:21: 58  
Systolic Pressure  
  
Diastolic Pressure  
  
Respiration Rate  
08:00:11: 15
```

```
    /*
* Health Monitoring System
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPATIENTS 5
#define MAXREADINGS 10
#define MAXTYPES 5
#define MAXTIME 8

/* One health type reading: timestamp + actual value */
typedef struct{
    char timestamp[MAXTIME+1];
    int value;
}Element;

/* Circular buffer of health type readings */
typedef struct{
    int start;  /* index of oldest reading */
    int end;    /* index of most current reading */
    Element reading[MAXREADINGS];
}CircularBuffer;

/* Patient's health chart: ID + multiple health type readings */
typedef struct{
    int id;
    CircularBuffer buffer[MAXTYPES];
}Chart;


/*
* Health records for all patients defined here.
* The variable record is visible to all functions
* in this file, i.e. it is global.
*/
Chart record[MAXPATIENTS];  

typedef enum{false,true} bool;

typedef char f_string[30] ;

typedef struct{
    int nfields ;
    f_string field[30] ;
}health_line;

bool is_end_of_field(char ch){
    return (ch == ',') || (ch == '\n') || (ch == EOF);
}

int min(int x, int y){
    return x < y ? x : y;
}


//read the next field from standard input

int get_field(f_string field){
    int nextIndex;
    int next_char;
    next_char = getchar();
    for(nextIndex = 0; ! is_end_of_field(next_char); nextIndex++){
        field[nextIndex] = next_char;
        next_char = getchar();  
    }
    field[nextIndex] = '\0';
    return next_char;

}
// reads in a csv line and fields is filled with data
health_line get_line(){
    health_line line;
    int currentChar = 0;
    int lastChar;
    lastChar = get_field(line.field[currentChar++]);
    while(lastChar == ','){
        lastChar = get_field(line.field[currentChar++]);
    }
    line.nfields = (lastChar == EOF) ? 0: currentChar;
    return line;
}


void print_health(health_line data){
    int i =0;

    for(i = 0; i <data.nfields; i++){

        printf("%s \n",  data.field[i]);
    }

}
void print_line(health_line data){
    int type = atoi(data.field[2]);
    double tempType = atoi(data.field[3]);
    int patientID = atoi(data.field[0]);
    int value = atoi(data.field[3]);


    if(type == 1){
        tempType = tempType/10.0;
        printf("%s Temperature for Patient ID = %d is %.1f \n",data.field[1],patientID,tempType );  
    }
    else if(type == 2){
        printf("%s Heart Rate for Patient ID = %d is %d \n",data.field[1],patientID,value );
    }
    else if(type == 3){
        printf("%s Systolic Pressure for Patient ID = %d is %d \n",data.field[1],patientID,value );
    }
    else if(type == 4){
        printf("%s Diastolic Pressure for Patient ID = %d is %d \n",data.field[1],patientID,value  );
    }
    else if(type == 5){
        printf("%s Respiration Rate for Patient ID = %d is %d \n",data.field[1],patientID, value );
    }
    else if(type == 6){
        printf("%s Print command entered for Patient ID = %d \n", data.field[1], patientID);
    }   

}




void main(health_line data){
int i, j;

/* initialize health data records for each patient */

for( i=0; i < MAXPATIENTS; i++ ){
    record[i].id = i + 1;
    for( j=0; j < MAXTYPES; j++ ){
        record[i].buffer[j].start = 0;
    record[i].buffer[j].end = 0;
        }

}

printf("Welcome to the Health Monitoring System\n\n");

/*
*  YOUR CODE GOES HERE:
*  (1) Read a csv line of health data from stdin 
*  (2) Parse csv line into appropriate fields
*  (3) Store health data in patient record or print if requested
*  (4) Continue (1)-(3) until EOF
* 
*/
    health_line arrayTotal[30];
    health_line current;
    current = get_line();
    arrayTotal[0]  = current;
    int k = 0;
    int Index = 0;
    int printValue = atoi(data.field[2]);
    health_line temp;
    int asci;
    asci = atoi(current.field[2]);
    int printAsci;
    printAsci = atoi(current.field[2]); 
    double tempValue = 0.0;
    tempValue = atof(current.field[3]);
    int patientID;

    Chart chart;
    int valueType;


    //stores the current line read in to a temp array 
    while(asci != 6){

        current = get_line();
        asci = atoi(current.field[2]);
        patientID = atoi(current.field[0]); 
        arrayTotal[asci - 1] = current;

        //copies from and to destination of the string of the timestamp and the value.
        strcpy(chart.buffer[asci].reading[chart.buffer[asci].end].timestamp, current.field[1]);

        //why is this line giving me seg fault  
    //  chart.buffer[asci].reading[chart.buffer[asci].end].value = atoi(current.field[3]);

        if(chart.buffer[asci].start == chart.buffer[asci].end){
            chart.buffer[asci].start++;
        }
        chart.buffer[asci].end++;


    }   


    printf("\nReading for Patient ID = %d\n",patientID);

    //attempt to print out the result of the strcpy
    //printf("%s",chart.buffer[asci]);


    /*

    //checks the second field within an array to compare it to a condition to print out a certain string for a category
    int p;  
    int l;
        for(p = 0; p < 8; p++){
        health_line temp;
        temp = arrayTotal[p];

        int type;
        type = atoi(temp.field[2]);
        if(type == 1){
            printf("Temperature:\n%s: %.1f\n",temp.field[1],tempValue/10.0);
        }
        else if(type == 2){
            printf("Heart Rate:\n%s: %s\n", temp.field[1],temp.field[3]);
        }
        else if(type == 3){
            printf("Systolic Pressure:\n%s %s\n", temp.field[1],temp.field[3]);
        }
        else if(type == 4){
            printf("Diastolic Pressure:\n%s: %s\n", temp.field[1], temp.field[3]);
        }
        else if(type == 5){
            printf("Respiration Rate:\n%s: %s\n", temp.field[1], temp.field[3]);        
        }

    }*/         
      }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate through the buffer?

Comment: I'm asking how to print the buffer.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do.  Four variables are set at the top of the `while` loop, but their types are unknown.  Three of them are unused in the code below.  And `buffer` is treated as a linear buffer, not a circular one, because the indices `start` and `end` are not prevented from running beyond the end.  Please see http://sscce.org/ to learn how to provide information that will help us answer your question.

Comment: The variables you mention are in my code but I didn't paste them. here let me put my whole code in.

Comment: You need to know how many elements are in the circular array. You could start with the first `Element`, and iterate through the lot, one at a time, printing each `Element` out individually, formatting via `printf`.

Comment: Check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer